# How do I test on a Surface Hub

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, surface-hub

I'm trying to use remote debugging to test an application on a Surface Hub. On my local machine, I'm using VS 2017. Both the local Windows 10 machine and the Surface Hub are running Creator's Update (15063). The Surface Hub and the local machine both have "Developer Mode" enabled.

I've set the authentication to Universal and put the Hub's IP address in as the remote machine name. When I press the Debug button, the Hub puts up a dialog with this:

```
C:\ProgramData\DeveloperTools\VSRemoteTools\x64\coreclr\CoreCLR.
dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try
installing the program again using the original installation media or
contact your system adminsitrator or the software vendor for support.
Error status 0xc0000428.
```

And on my local machine I get this:

```
 DEP0100: Please ensure that target device has
          developer mode enabled. Could not obtain a
          developer license on 10.10.1.17 due to error
          80004005.
```

Googling around I found that `0xc0000428` is usually a digital signature issue.

I'm aware that I can package up the app and install test certificates and stuff. But I'm hoping there's a way to get VS 2017's debugger to work the way the documentation says it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an known bug that got introduced in Visual Studio 15.3 update (CoreCLR did not get signed with certificates required by Surface Hub). It is also tracked here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/107166/visual-studio-153-isnt-able-to-remote-deploy-uwp-a.html

It should be fixed in next Visual Studio update.